# Rails update author_id in books table after deleting and creating a new author record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Here is the `Author` model and `Book` model

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

I create 2 authors (author1 & author2) and added 2 books for each one.

Afterwards I deleted author1 and created a new author (author3). Now, I want to give author3 the two books of author1.

Is there an ActiveRecord method to update the books author_id with the new author?

Comment: `books.update_all(author_id: <author_id>)` no?

Comment: @SebastianPalma But what if there are other books with different author_id?

Comment: You can group them. Isn't clear what you're trying to do. Can you explain further?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yeah sure. Updated the question

Comment: After you deleted `author1`, the books of `author1` are also destroyed.

Comment: @MarekLipka At the time of deletion the dependent: :destroy parameter was not specified in the Author model.

Comment: @vishnuprasanth what? `dependent: :destroy` will delete the author and it's associated books on destroy. It seems like the association should be optional if books can be assigned to a different author...doesn't make sense logically though

Comment: @MarkMerritt At first I did not add that line in the Author model. Added it after destroying author1

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to first create the second author. If you delete the first author first then you won't be able to fetch the books associated with the first author.

### Find the new author

```
new_author = Author.find(new_id)
```

### Change the books from the old author to the new one

```
old_author = Author.find(old_id)
old_author.books.update_all(author_id: new_author.id)
```

### Delete the old author

```
old_author.destroy
```

This would ensure no data is lost and also no orphan data is present.

Comment: Note that `update_all` will not run callbacks. Instead you could do something like `author_1.books.each { |book| book.update_attributes(author_id: author_2.id) }`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the book object to stick around after you delete the author so you can then assign it to another author.  If that is the case, you might want to consider using a has and belongs to many relationship: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association.  So you would have 3 tables: `authors`, `books` and `authors_books`. `author_books` would only have 2 columns: `author_id` and `book_id`.

Another option would be to change `Author` like so:

```
  class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :books, dependent: :nullify
  end
```

Now when an author is deleted, the books are not deleted, instead `author_id` is set to null in the books table for all the books that previously belonged to a particular author: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent